# How do I use persistent mode on the LiveCD?

Tags: 11.10, live-cd, persistence

I followed the tutorial [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence) but I'm stuck at the part where I need to add ''persistent'' on the ''kernel arguments list''. I don't know how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Before you reboot there are only two things that you need to remember. When the Live CD menu gets displayed hit the  key to
>   enter “Other Options”. This will display the arguments that the Live
>   CD passes to the kernel. At the end of this argument list just add a
>   space and add the word “persistent”. This will instruct the Live CD to
>   maintain and use persistence. That is all. Go for it!

[image]

To display this screen,  immediately when you see the purple screen with the symbol at the bottom (seen immediately after the boot sequence starts)  press <kbd>Esc</kbd>... If you got to the "try ubuntu screen" you missed the opportunity!

enter the word *persistent* as shown.

When you press <kbd>F6</kbd> a pop-up menu will display.  Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to make this menu disappear then use the keyboard arrow keys to move to the position shown in the picture.

Comment: Is that menu still available in the more recent ubuntu releases? Is it just really fast (so you need to press a hotkey) to show it?

Comment: yes - this is the 11.10 screen I just ran up on a virtualbox guest.

Comment: What am I doing wrong? http://youtu.be/rhvqnVvHoLc

Comment: Immediately when you see the purple screen with the symbol at the bottom press Escape... If you got to the "try ubuntu screen" you missed the opportunity!

Answer (score 2):

When you boot the flash drive, at the boot splash, hit the <kbd>F6</kbd> button.

You will see the options listed at the bottom, navigate on the line with the options with the arrow keys, add in `persistent`

```
quiet splash persistent --
```

If it is working, you can edit `syslinux.cfg` on the flash driver. This file is your boot menu. Edit or add a new entry.

Note: When I use persistence, I use 2 menu entries, one with and one without persistence.

Also take care, persistence uses a bit of space if you update your packages. If you are going to do that, I would suggest a standard install. You might also want to just use a persistent home.

FWIW, you can do this graphically with unetbootin and the Universal USB Installer

[unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) is in the ubuntu repositories and runs on Windows

[image: unetbootin]

[Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

[image: Universal USB Installer]

Comment: Can I do this with a CD/DVD?

Comment: Depending on what exactly you want to do with a CD/DVD, almost certainly yes

Comment: I'm talking about adding persistence option on my LiveCD(like the last pic)

Comment: yes, you can use your live cd or iso to make a persistent flash drive.