# What does the "persistent" in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX do?

Tags: grub2

I was editing my Grub file to disable the splash screen, and I saw this line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="persistent"
```

What does this command do? Google doesn't help, talking about USB persistance without mentionning Grub itself, and Grub documentation only says that `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` is used for recovery options.

Answer (score 0):

It's a boot parameter to be used to Boot the Live CD in Persistent Mode.
Here are the links from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/89106/915838) and [ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence?action=show&redirect=LiveCDPersistence#Automatic_Persistence).